# Segment pdf, doc, docx documents into paragraph level texts

Tags: pdf, nlp, docx, text-extraction, doc

I want to parse several long scientific documents for a **NER** task. The documents come as pdf, doc and docx and, unfortunately, do not share the same structure.

I seek to extract the raw text from the documents in Python, while creating sub-documents for tables and text.

I have functions that reliably extract the text from the documents and write them, together with the document labels, in a list.

```py
import re, os
import textract, PyPDF2
​
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
def get_doc_content(filename):
  text = textract.process(filename).decode("utf-8")
  return re.sub("[\n|]", " ", text) 

def get_pdf_content(filename):
  pdf_file = open(filename, mode='rb')
  pdf_doc = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
  current_page = 0
  text = ''
  while(current_page < pdf_doc.numPages ):  
    page = pdf_doc.getPage(current_page)
    text += re.sub("[\n]","", page.extractText()) 
    current_page += 1
  return text

input_dir = '/my_path.../'
file_names = []
content = []
for fname in os.listdir(input_dir):
  fpath = os.path.join(input_dir, fname)
  if fname.endswith(".doc") or fname.endswith(".docx"):
    file_names.append(fname)
    content.append(get_doc_content(fpath))    
  elif fname.endswith(".pdf"):
    file_names.append(fname)
    content.append(get_pdf_content(fpath))    
  else:
    print ('file type not supported: %s' % (fname))
    continue

df= pd.DataFrame({'text':content, 'doc_label':file_names})
```

This gives me following output -  looking at the first entry:
**Output1:**

```py
df.head(1)
>>> text                doc_label
    extracted raw text...   doc_1
```

The parsed file, however, contains several tables and long raw text, so I seek to have an output similar to this (for the first example file). 
**Output2:**

```py
df
>>> text              par_label        doc_label
    extracted table 1...  table_1          doc_1
    extracted table 2...  table_2          doc_1
    extracted text 1...   text_1           doc_1       
    extracted table 3...  table_3          doc_1
    extracted text 2...   text_2           doc_1
    .
    .
    .
```

**My question:** How can I adjust my code (are there Python workarounds) to detect tables/text chunks in those documents and obtain **output2** instead of **output1**.

I do not need to have a perfect automatism for this, but some way to segment those documents would be very helpful.

Comment: Could you clarify better what is your question?

Comment: updated. hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the data are documents, a hierarchical data structure will be more useful than a list. The hierarchical data structures include Python's dict, JSON, or XML.